# unknow mutation type usin Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

**component**

```
computed: {
   score () {
    this.$store.commit('geolocation');
    console.log(this.$store.getters.lat);
   }
}
```

**store.js**

```
export default {
  state: {
   lat:'ok',
  },
  getters:{
    cordinate(state){
    return state.lat
    }
  },  
  mutations: {
    geolocation(state){
     state.lat
    }
  },
  actions: {
  }
}
```

**App.js**

```
import StoreData from'./store.js';
Vue.use(Vuex);
const store = new Vuex.Store({StoreData});
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {},
  router: router,
   store,
})
```

**New to vuex. Tried to get value from vuex . but stuck on this error:[vuex] unknown mutation type. am i missing something ?**

Comment: not a vuex pro but do you need to define your store.js as a vuex module event?
`const store = new Vuex.Store({ modules: { events: StoreData } });`

Comment: your mutation does nothing. you have to assign a value. you can pass a payload to your mutations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should assign some value to your state property as follows:

```
computed: {
   score () {
    this.$store.commit('geolocation',78);
    console.log(this.$store.getters.lat);
   }
}
```

```
  mutations: {
    geolocation(state,newLat){
     state.lat=newLat;
    }
  }
```

when using Vuex store it is recommended to use `mutations` and `actions` inside methods and getters inside computed properties.

**The source of issue**

> In your `main.js` you should have `const store = new Vuex.Store(StoreData);` instead of <del>`const store = new Vuex.Store({StoreData});`</del> by removing `{}` around `StoreData`